# Underscore in Upvar declaration

Tags: tcl

While declaring SBPort in the below code section as upvar, why an underscore is prefixed? 
Inside this function if I want to print the array how do I do? Because if I try to print with "puts" it is considering  $_SBPort($DutPort) as a comment.

```
proc GetCapturedFrames { DutPorts SBPort} {
  upvar $SBPort _SBPort

  foreach DutPort $DutPorts {
    set card [lindex $_SBPort($DutPort) 1]
    set port [lindex $_SBPort($DutPort) 2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore is just another character allowed in a variable name. I presume the programmer wanted the local variable to have a name that was similar to the name of the variable that is being linked to, but not actually the same name.

There is nothing in the code you have posted that indicates why `puts $_SBPort($DutPort)` would be considered a comment, and indeed it should print the value in question. Note that (assuming the code isn't wildly wrong) `_SBPort` is an array (a collection of variable names of the form `_SBPort(<member name>)`), while `$_SBPort($DutPort)` seems to be a list (a sequence of values).